# Fetching and concatenate two rows value from two different table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, subquery

I am unable to Fetch and concatenate two rows value from two different table in SQL. 
Please see my query in attached photo.
Following query doesn't providing me the exact data

```
SELECT RequestNo+'::'+convert(varchar(200),(select count(RID)+1 
                                            from BDProjectProposal 
                                            Group by RID)) AS Number
FROM       BDRequestorInfo
WHERE     (RID = @RID)
```

Is there any way?

[image: Photo]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below

```
SELECT RequestNo+'::'+convert(varchar(200),isnull((select count(RID)+1 
                                            from BDProjectProposal 
                                            Group by RID
                                            having RID = @RID),1) AS Number
FROM       BDRequestorInfo
WHERE     (RID = @RID)
```

I only added WHERE clause (having RID = @RID) in Subselect to ensure that there will be only one value returning.

Your subselect returns a dataset causing possibly an SQL error

I modified above query and added ISNULL(....,1) for NULL returns with no rows for a given @RID

Comment: Thank you. Its not returning any value if count(RID)=0.

Comment: We can modify and add ISNULL() to prevent if no rows exists for given @RID as follows.   
select isnull((select count(RID)+1 
from BDProjectProposal 
Group by RID
having RID = @RID),1)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT (RequestNo + '::' +
        convert(varchar(200),
                (select count(RID) + 1 
                 from BDProjectProposal pp
                 where pp.RID = ri.RID)
                ) 
               )
       ) AS Number
FROM BDRequestorInfo ri
WHERE ri.RID = @RID;
```